# How to calculate circle size in pixels in react-native-maps

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I'm using react-native-maps to create circles on a map. When a user applies a long press and then drags up or down, I dynamically adjust the radius of the circle. However, this approach is causing lagging issues. To mitigate this, I've implemented an animated view circle on the map.

Now, the problem I'm facing is that I can't seem to adjust the size of my animated view circle to match the circle on the map. Initially, I set the map circle radius to 20 meters. However, when I zoom out, the map circle remains at 20 meters, while my animated view circle appears larger.

I'm seeking a method to calculate the map circle radius in pixels so that I can adjust both circles to be the same size. Any insights on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!